# Is 1/vector is a vector or not?

Tags: vectors, geometry, mathematics

Let $\vec { A } = a \hat { i } + b \hat { j } + c \hat { k }$. Is $\frac { 1 } { \vec { A } }$ a vector or not, and if it is, then what are its components?"

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Not necessarily. If the OP wondered whether $A_i/A^2$ transforms as a vector does, math.se will be more likely than phys.se to overlook that. It does, BTW.